# Java 8 Lambda variable scope

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have 2 code samples:

```
int[] idx = { 0 };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
list.add("ghi");
list.stream().forEach(item -> {
    System.out.println(idx[0] + ": " + item);
    idx[0]++;
});
```

Working properly.

While this code has compile error:

```
int idx = 0;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
list.add("ghi");
list.stream().forEach(item -> {
    System.out.println(idx + ": " + item);
    idx++;
});
```

Saying:

```
Local variable idx defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.
```

The only difference is `idx` int or int array.

What's the root cause?

Comment: i cant tell you why exactly it is like that but if you make idx static and move it outside the main method it works fine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes, I tried make idx static and move it outside the main method, working fine. But why? Could you help share more details?

Comment: I'd add that `.forEach` applies to list and not to a stream:
`list.forEach(item -> {...`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777915/java-8-catch-22-with-lambda-expressions-and-effectively-final and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374961/solve-no-final-variable-inside-java-8-stream/38375344#38375344

Comment: I don't think that any of the three alternatives provided by Tunaki is a good duplicate. All three are answering parts of the question, but none of them is addressing the direct comparison of why the code with `int[]` array works, while an almost identical code with `int` does not.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961578/why-lambda-forces-me-to-use-single-element-array-instead-of-final-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554515/using-final-1-element-array-for-anonymous-inner-class (though not in the context of a lambda)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root cause is that JVM lacks mechanisms of constructing references to local variables, which is what is needed to perform `idx++` when `idx` is an `int` or some immutable type (e.g. `String`). Since you try to mutate `idx`, simply capturing its value would not be sufficient; Java would need to capture a reference, and then modify the value through it.

Java does not have this problem when you use an array, because arrays are reference objects. Java can capture array reference that never changes, and use that non-changing reference to mutate the object. Array itself provides the necessary level of indirection, because Java arrays are mutable.

> I tried make `idx` static and move it outside the main method, working fine. But why?

Because in this situation there is no need for the lambda to capture a reference to a local variable of primitive type. A reference to the static variable is readily available, so there is no problem with capturing it.

Similarly, the code would work if you make `idx` a member variable, and use your lambda inside an instance method. This would let lambda modify `idx` field through `this` object, which could be freely captured.

Comment: Java lacks pointers to local variables in general. It doesn’t matter whether the type of the variable is primitive or not, the local variable can’t be changed. And that’s a good thing, as local variables have a fixed life time and having a pointer to them that could last longer, is exactly what Java prevents.

Comment: This is a great answer, helped me understand this too. With that understanding I now add my variable as a single value in an array[] and reference array[0] to manipulate it to get around this error.

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial explanation for your observations.  The initialized array in your Java 8 code is considered as **effectively final**, because its value does not change after initialization.  This is why the `int[] idx = { 0 };` version of your code is getting through.  So I would expect if you make `int idx` effectively final, then it would also pass.  One way to do this would be to *formally* make this variable final by declaring it so, i.e. `final int idx = 0`.

Comment: Why do you think, the “value can never change after initialization”? You can simply write `idx=new int[42];` right afterwards. `idx` is only effectively final, because the code doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 1):

A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is **effectively final.**

In case 1:

`int[] idx` don't change, if you replace `idx[0]++;` to `idx = {1};` will compile error

In case 2:

if you remove `idx++`; it will compile fine